# How can app detect JS performance of the host device?

Tags: javascript, performance, web-applications

I have a performance heavy HTML5/Canvas app. I want to limit some of the features if the JS execution slows down like on a mobile or low-spec laptop.

I am measuring timestamps of various functions but the results vary also based on the content of the app (what XML is parsed, what is drawn on the canvas).

Is there a more deterministic approach? How can the app detect the JS performance of the host device?

Comment: you should take this question to Code review  https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam I don't think CodeReview is the right place to ask for a direction for a code that I have not written yet.

Comment: Your statement **I have a performance heavy HTML5/Canvas app. I want to limit some of the features if the JS execution slows down like on a mobile or low-spec laptop** didnt let me guess that it wasnt developed yet

Comment: FPS is a good metric for graphic-related apps. Isn't FPS enough for your scene?